# How can i change generated name of file when useing array of files?

Tags: c

I am new to programming and i have a problem where i u se  and i need to make many files to write in >15 so i dont whant to do it manualy i used array of files. That works fine but the problem starts when i need to give a location of every file and by using a "for cyclus" i cant change the names of files in destinations here is part of code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
int i;
FILE *files[14];
for(i=0;i<15;i++)
files[i]=fopen("C:\\File.txt" ,"w");
}
for(i=0;i<15;i++)
fclose(files[i]);
getch();
}
```

problem is with fopen function because it opens only 1st file, but not others... 
if u need some more explaining please ask will try to provede as much as possible.. thanks

Comment: Seeing as how this is all C, can you at least use something like `"C:\\File" + std::to_string(i) + ".txt"`?

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<14;i++)` instead of `for(i=1;i<15;i++)`

Comment: @chris: I'm pretty sure `std::to_string` isn't going to work in C (but should in C++, which fits the tag).

Comment: @JerryCoffin, Yeah, that's what I meant. Should the tag be C++ or C, as in are C++ solutions even allowed, as the code as is, is C.

Comment: sorry droped some lines... all variables are defined.@chris will try this solution. also sorry for miss taging but i think thisis c++ because i am workingin DevC++? I am rly new to this so i am sorry..

Comment: for (int i=0; i < 13; i++) is wrong

Comment: Can you edit your sample to something that will at least compile, it's pretty pathetic at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only supplying one name, so instead of trying to open 15 files, you're trying to open one file 15 times. Unless you specify a sharing mode, that will fail (at least with most compilers on Windows, which seems to be what you're using).

My guess is you want to open 15 different files though, in which case you need to specify 15 different file names. One possibility for doing that is to synthesize names that include the index. Since you appear to be using C (despite the `c++` tag) I'll stick to C for the moment.

```
int i;
FILE *f[15];

for (i=0; i<15; i++) {
    char name[32];

    sprintf(name, "File%d.txt", i);
    f[i] = fopen(name, "w");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much this realy helped me alot... I also aprishiate your understanding for my not knowing...

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to first define what array of files you will be using.

So when you declare FILE *files[14], you need to actually specify what each of those files are.

You should first declare a set of strings instead with the specific filenames, and loop over them.

Also, your for loops are wrong, it should be

```
for(i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
...
}
```

You need to start indexing at 0, and stop indexing at 13.